# Possible to tie in to Breeze's Transaction Context?

Tags: javascript, entity-framework, entity-framework-5, breeze

We are using BreezeJS with an EntityFramework backend.  Part of our requirements is that we execute stored procedures on our server during the Breeze SaveChanges.  Our problem is that we can't ensure transaction integrity unless we can piggy-back our stored procedure calls into breeze's ambient transaction.

We are unable to perform the operations of the stored procedures through data manipulation because of management.

***tldr***; can we use breeze's EFContext's transaction scope to execute stored procedures along with the usual SaveChanges

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for taking so long.

It's a good question and something that makes a good deal of sense. But... we don't have a great answer right now that doesn't involve actually modifying the Breeze.WebApi dll. Please  add this as a feature request to the [Breeze User Voice](https://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions). We take this venue very seriously in determining what to work on next.

Another alternative is to send an email to [breeze@ideablade.com](http://breeze@ideablade.com).  They have consultants that have an in depth knowledge of Breeze and could conceivably make the modifications as well.

Comment: Request added http://breezejs.uservoice.com/forums/173093-breeze-feature-suggestions/suggestions/3913813-support-executing-arbitrary-stored-procedures-with